# Mathematical description of the ACF using fft2

Tags: fft, autocorrelation

I computed the acf of an image with the following code:

```
%# read in image
Img = imread('myImage.tif');

% get size of image
[N, M] = size(Img);

%# convert to double
I = double(Img); 

%# subtract mean
I = I-mean(I(:)); 

%# normalize magnitude
I = I/sqrt(sum(I(:).^2)); 

%# compute acf
fft_I = fft2(I); 
Acf = real(fftshift(ifft2(fft_I.*conj(fft_I))));
```

Now, i have to mathematically describe the procedure, and I am thinking that the FFT equation given in https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft2.html (scroll to the bottom) isn't enough?

Can someone please help me out here. Many thanks.

EDIT:
Please find the added mathematical description i have come up with and kindly help me verify its correctness.
[image]

Comment: Don't you have to pad extra data to compute the auto-correlation using the FFT?

Comment: Thanks @Ben. I'm aware of that.

Comment: i think you need to zero-pad your data to twice the length before the FFT and then the resulting ACF will have a triangular envelope inherently applied to it.  [McLeod and Wyvill](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/60dd/4c01f687858a5fbf6c021920c56247bcf2db.pdf) call this *"ACF type 2"*,

Answer (score 1):

When the signal is assumed to be ergodic, then its ACF can be computed using time averages which can also be computed using the following convolution of length $N$ sequence $x[n]$ by its conjugate symmetric version:

$$ \hat{r}_{xx}[m] = \frac{1}{N} ~~~x[m] ~~\star ~~ x^*[-m] ~~ $$

Taking the $2N-1$ point DFT of both sides yields the following:

$$ \hat{R}_{xx}[k] = \frac{1}{N} ~~~X[k] X^*[k] =  \frac{1}{N} |X[k]|^2  $$

In a MATLAB implementation, an *fftshift* is required to bring $r_{xx}[0]$ to the center position for convenience. Hence the ACF will be obtained by an $2N-1$ point inverse DFT/FFT as

`rxk = (1/N)*real(fftshift( ifft( abs(fft(x,2N-1)).^2 ,2N-1) ) );`

The 2D case follows very similarly to this 1D outline...

Comment: Thank you @Fat32. If i get you correctly, it means that `abs(fft(x)).^2` is the same as  `fft(x).*conj(fft(x))` ?

Comment: @oma11 Yes, that's correct.

Comment: i think it might be appropriate to caution you guys about the need to zero-pad your data to twice the length before the FFT and then the resulting ACF has a triangular envelope inherently applied to it.  [McLeod and Wyvill](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/60dd/4c01f687858a5fbf6c021920c56247bcf2db.pdf) call this *"ACF type 2"*.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I think that's not necessary (or I didin't understand your statement) as the FFT function will already be inherently doing the zero-padding when you take 2*L-1 point FFT of an L point sequence ?

Comment: @Fat32, the FFT doesn't zero pad.  if you have $L$ samples and you're DFT is expecting $2L$ samples, somehow you gotta define all of those $2L$ samples.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson alright, again I'm assuming MATLAB **default** behaviour; given a sequence $x[n]$ of length $L$ the command `X = fft(x,2*L)` inherently zero pads the sequence to length $2L$ hence it's equivalent to the command `X = fft( [x,zeros(1,L)],2*L)`... that's MATLAB FFT default bahaviour, I'm not sure about other languages though...

Comment: until now, i didn't realize that MATLAB's `fft( )` did that.  i've always had just one argument to `X=fft(x)`.

Comment: still, the result of the ACF done this way is:

$$ R_x[k] = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N/2 \, -1-k} x[n]x[n+k] $$

where $N$ is the DFT size and the latter $N/2$ samples of $x[n]$ are zero. 
 With that $-k$ in the upper limit of the summation, the number of terms summed decreases as $k$ increases which effectively applies a decreasing linear slope onto the magnitude of $R_x[k]$.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I'm indeed grateful. I have now come up with what I think should be an equation representing the 2D ACF using FFT methods. I do not know how to write the equation in the comment section, hence, i have added it as an attachment to the main question. Please, kindly help me verify its accuracy.

Comment: @oma11 honestly I cannot decipher your edit into your question...

Comment: @Fat32 what I'm trying to achieve is to get the mathematical representation of the 2D ACF in terms of FFT. I've added a few more lines to the edit. Please have a look again. Thank you.